# How to bind click events on kendoui web gridview custom command

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

These codes use for get command data from ajax, and it's working:

```
function command(){
    var res;
    $.ajax({
        url: "../data/sys_user.service.php?method=getUserCommand&onpage="+"<?php echo EL::CurPage(); ?>",
        async:false,
        success: function (json) {var r = $.parseJSON(json);res=r;},
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(jqXHR.responseText);},
        complete: function(){}
    });
    return res;
};
```

The function return json data like:

```
[
{"id":22,"text":"Edit","name":"edit"},
{"id":23,"text":"Remove","name":"destroy"},
{"id":45,"text":"Change Password","name":"changeUserPwd","click":"changeUserPwd"}
]
```

Of course, Kendo-ui grid view can use the result, and grid command "Edit" and "Remove" is working:

```
.....
    columns: [
        { field: "id", title:"#", width:20,filterable: false},
        { field: "username", title:"Username", width:100},
        { field: "userpwd", title:"Password", width:200, filterable: false, hidden:true},
        { field: "name", title:"Name", width:100 },
        { field: "email", title:"E-Mail" ,width:200 },
        { command: command(),},
    ],
.....



function changeUserPwd(e){
    alert('Change Password !');
}
```

Now, the issue is the command "Change Password" do nothing when click it.

How to bind events on the commands those using remote data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. May be it will help you.

```
<script>

function changeUserPwd(year) {
    alert(year);
}

var movies = [
                    { "rank": 1, "rating": 9.2, "year": 1994, "title": "The Shawshank Redemption", "click": "changeUserPwd" },
                    { "rank": 2, "rating": 9.2, "year": 1972, "title": "The Godfather", "click": "changeUserPwd" },
                    { "rank": 3, "rating": 9, "year": 1974, "title": "The Godfather: Part II", "click": "" }

                ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: movies,
            pageSize: 10
        },
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "rank",
            width: 90,
            title: "rank"
        }, {
            field: "title",
            width: 90,
            title: "title"
        },
        {
            template: "# if( click !== '') { # <input class='k-button' type='button' onclick='#: click #(#: year #);' value='click me' /> # } else {#<span>Click Field is empty<span>#} #", width: 90
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the "click" handler to:

```
"click":"changeUserPwd"
```

which is a `string`, NOT a reference to a `function`.

Jayesh's answer shows a way to have a column template that adds a button that executes a function that has the same name as what you specified. However, I don't think that will work well with the built-in commands.

You can sort of get around this by specifying a `template` INSTEAD of a `click` (you can also remove the "name" property on the custom command) like this:

```
[
  {"id":22,"text":"Edit","name":"edit"},
  {"id":23,"text":"Remove","name":"destroy"},
  {
    "text":"Change Password",
    "template": "<a class='k-button k-button-icontext href='\\#' onclick='window.changeUserPwd()'><span></span>#=text#</a>"
  }
]
```

And move the scope of your function to the window (just in case. sometimes there are weird scope issues since it gets wrapped in a Kendo Template.)

```
window.changeUserPwd = function (e){
    alert('Change Password !');
}
```

Then this will start working.
However, there is no "context" or event passed to the `changeUserPwd` function, so `e` parameter passed in will just be `undefined`.

---

**The much better answer:**

After I thought about this more, this is a better solution:

In the `success` function of your AJAX call, just replace the `click` for each command with the reference to the function, instead of a string. Example:

(this syntax probably isn't 100% correct. I am typing it off the top of my head.)

```
var customCommands = {
    changeUserPwd: function (e) { ... }
};

$.ajax({
    ...

    success: function (json) {
        var r = $.parseJSON(json);

        // for each response, if it has a 'click' specified, go find the function
        $.each(r, function () {
            if(r.click) {
                r.click = customCommands[r.click]; // get the function by its name.
            }
        });

        res=r;
    }

    ...
});
```

Now the Kendo Grid should bind the command handlers correctly, since they are actual references to functions instead of strings.